# Fastest way to cast all dataframe columns to float - pandas astype slow

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Is there a faster way to cast all columns of a pandas dataframe to a single type? This seems particularly slow:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(np.float64), axis=1)
```

I suspect there's not much I can do about it because of the memory allocation overhead of `numpy.ndarray.astype`.

I've also tried `pd.to_numeric` but it arbitrarily chooses to cast a few of my columns into `int` types instead.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No need for [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), just use [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) directly.

```
df.astype(np.float64)
```

`apply`-ing is also going to give you a pretty bad performance hit.

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10**7).reshape(10**4, 10**3))

%timeit df.astype(np.float64)
1 loop, best of 3: 288 ms per loop

%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(np.float64), axis=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 748 ms per loop

%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(np.float64), axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.95 s per loop
```

Answer (score 6):

One efficient way would be to work with array data and cast it back to a dataframe, like so -

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.astype(np.float64))
```

Runtime test -

```
In [144]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(11,99,(5000,5000)))

In [145]: %timeit df.astype(np.float64) # @Mitch's soln
10 loops, best of 3: 121 ms per loop

In [146]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(df.values.astype(np.float64))
10 loops, best of 3: 42.5 ms per loop
```

The casting back to dataframe wasn't that costly -

```
In [147]: %timeit df.values.astype(np.float64)
10 loops, best of 3: 42.3 ms per loop # Casting to dataframe costed 0.2ms
```

Comment: It is faster but it destroys the column names. When setting back the column names it takes similar time as doing `df.astype(np.float64)`. +1 For my application, I didn't need all the column names back so I partially set the column names I needed, and this led to a huge performance boost!